# Efficient way to check if the file exists at start-up

Tags: java, file

So far I came with this solution, but I wonder if there is more efficient way to do this.
Pseudo-code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
boolean FileNotFound = false;
FileReader file = new FileReader("path");
   try (BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(file){
   //nothing to execute here
   }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      FileNotFound = true; 
      }
if (FileNotFound) {
//generate the file
 } 
}
```

Comment: `File.exists()`?

Comment: If you want to make sure it's a file, and not a directory, use [`File.isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
public static boolean fileExists(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    return file.exists();
}
```

And then just call it with

```
...
if(fileExists("path")) ...
...
```